# :first-letter having difficulty in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, html

I have a simple style for a 'dropcap' type design for `p` tags in my CSS.

```
p.introduction:first-letter {
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman' , Times, serif;
    font-size: 300%;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.08em;
    margin-bottom: -0.25em;
}
```

This seems to be working fine across all browsers, however I am getting peculiar behavior in Firefox. The letter drops down into the text below it.

Normally, I would debug it in Firebug, but here's the strange part - It doesn't show up in Firebug! I really have no clue what is causing it. I have reproduced it in the following jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/4zMex/

My standard browser is Chrome. This works in Safari and IE9 as well. Only Firefox exhibits the strange behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing your negative margin-bottom solves the problem. Why is this needed?

Comment: Because in every other browser, the spacing is way too much without it. So then, what do I do? It looks wrong in every other browser if I make it look right in FireFox...

Comment: If you replace the margin-bottom with height: 0.8em, it fixes Firefox and doesn't break other browsers (at least not Chrome ;-))

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought to try increasing it to get the desired effect.